# Tag synonym page missing after tag merge and swap

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms

The [tag synonym](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/simcity/synonyms) and [top users](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/simcity/topusers) page for the [simcity] tag on Arqade went missing after a [mod merged it with [simcity-2013]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest), and another mod swapped the direction of the merge so that the direction of the merge points from [simcity-2013] to [simcity].

[image]

<sup>(Courtesy of badp)</sup>

Chat conversation: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8122873#8122873

Comment: TIL there's a new SimCity coming out. Awesome ;)

Comment: Getting [good reviews](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/gamesblog/2013/feb/04/simcity-preview) as well @Yannis...